# How to store / access a global state object in Silverlight? (phone7)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm building an application on Phone 7 using Silverlight and need to maintain some state between pages.  I was hoping to store an object in app.cs and access it from each page but I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

What is the best way to access the same object between many different pages?

Thanks for your time,

-- Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question.  I can access objects in app.cs by simply doing:

```
App app = (App)Application.Current;
app.whateverMyObjectIsCalled
```

Is this a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: This is reasonable for applications of moderate complexity.

Comment: If you store your object as a static property, you don't need to cast Application.Current to App, you should just be able to access App.whateverMyObjectIsCalled directly.

Comment: You should be careful about cross thread access to such objects and be sure to lock or use monitor.enter/exit to avoid race conditions. You may also find issues accessing the object from some non-UI threads. In such cases you should look to execute such access on the UI thread.

Comment: You will also have some issues with unit testing if you are doing any, since you're relying on static objects to fill dependencies.